# NameError: global name 'win32netcon' is not defined

Tags: python, pywin32

Hey I'm trying to run scripts in Python 2.7 and I've downloaded the matching Python for Windows extension package. For some reason I'm still getting this error. Does anyone know where I can download win32netcon?

```
win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
NameError: global name 'win32netcon' is not defined
```

Comment: If you use a name in your code, you need to import it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import win32netcon first.

```
import win32wnet, win32netcon

win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK, password, username, flags)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are often frowned upon. Try to see if you can accompany the code in your answer with some text.